# HtmlUnit works different when i debug and run my code

Tags: htmlunit

I'm using `HtmlUnit` to parse html with js code. The structure of the page is(using Chrome Developer Tools):
[image]

And my code is as follow:

```
    WebClient wc=new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11);
    wc.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wc.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    wc.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);
    wc.getOptions().setDoNotTrackEnabled(false);
    HtmlPage page= wc.getPage(address);
    List<HtmlDivision> items=(List<HtmlDivision>)page.getByXPath(
            "/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@class='content_main']/div[@class='search_result']/div[@id='resultData']");
    System.out.println(items);
    if(items!=null && items.size()>0){
        HtmlDivision resultMain=items.get(0);
        List<HtmlDivision> appDivList=(List<HtmlDivision>)resultMain.getByXPath(".//div[contains(@class,'search_one')]");
        System.out.println(appDivList);
        for(HtmlDivision resultItem:appDivList){
            try{
                DomElement appImgInfo=resultItem.getFirstElementChild();
                List<HtmlDivision> appInfoList=(List<HtmlDivision>)resultItem.getByXPath("./div[@class='one_right']");
                String appName=null;
```

The problem is when i debug this code, it works fine. When i run this code,

```
List<HtmlDivision> appDivList=(List<HtmlDivision>)resultMain.getByXPath(".//div[contains(@class,'search_one')]");
```

doesn't work,that is `appDivList` is empty, but when i debug this code, `appDivList`is not empty.
Anyone know why?

---

Update:

I add some `Thread.sleep` code before

```
  List<HtmlDivision> appDivList=(List<HtmlDivision>)resultMain.getByXPath(".//div[contains(@class,'search_one')]");
```

The updated code is:

```
        HtmlDivision resultMain=items.get(0);
        try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        List<HtmlDivision> appDivList=(List<HtmlDivision>)resultMain.getByXPath(".//div[contains(@class,'search_one')]");
        System.out.println(appDivList);
```

It works! How does this happen?

Comment: Maybe version issue, Did U confirmed it in newest version ???

Comment: I update the HtmlUnit to the latest version 2.21, but it still doesn't work without the Sleep code

Comment: Did You tried it with css selector ???

Comment: I try css selector, and my code is: DomNodeList<DomNode> appDivList=resultMain.querySelectorAll("div.search_one"); However, it still doesn't work without the Thread.sleep code, and if add the Thread.sleep code, it works.

Comment: Does it work in other browser without sleep ???

Comment: I try all the browser that contained in the newest htmlUnit. Here is my result: only CHROME works fine without Thread.sleep code while BEST_SUPPORTED,EDGE,FIREFOX_38,FIREFOX_45,INTERNET_EXPLORER,INTERNET_EXPLORER_11 can't work. But all browser work with Thread.sleep code.

Comment: Did You searched in known htmlunit issues ???